# AJAX + PHP - Can't return a value from PHP to Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having trouble returning a variable from PHP to Ajax. When I remove the if statement and echo something simple as a number or a regular string, everything works fine. But once I try to do what I truly want, I receive nothing.

***AJAX CALL***

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(1); // For testing purposes.
    listContent = document.getElementById("scrolltask").outerHTML;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: location.pathname + 'refreshlist.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{"listContent":listContent},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

***PHP***

```
<?php
$listContent = $_POST['listContent'];
$db = new SQLite3('../../database.db');
$query = "SELECT tasks FROM todo";
$result = $db->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    $dbresult = $row["tasks"];
}

if ($listContent == $dbresult) {
    echo $dbresult;
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to do: check for update in the database. If there's an update, I will use the returned value to update the DOM.
*Note: I'm checking them if they hold the same value temporarily. I am working on a to-do list and it'd be easier to check if they are the same rather than updating the list on every single reload.*

Comment: You need to debug the content of `$listContent` and `$dbresult`. They likely aren't the same, so nothing is getting echoed. This line `$dbresult = $row["tasks"];` looks incorrect. You are overwriting the value of the `$dbresult` variable on each iteration.

Comment: Even if I simply echo both of them, without an if statement, they don't appear for some reason. I also tried to check if they are not the same.

Comment: Update: So I tried echoing the `$dbresult` value only (in the PHP file itself, it didn't display in the page where the Ajax call takes place. It worked but I sadly can't say the same for `$listContent`. My guess is that the whole problem comes from this value... which is weird, I did the same procedure yesterday with sending such value to the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try outputting that value as JSON:

```php
echo json_encode($dbresult);
```

Comment: Even though I deleted the comment, please ignore it in case you or somebody else has seen it! I didn't test it properly! Everything is working fine now, **_@Robo Robok_**! I'm really thankful for the help!